# Spring Expression Language use map as context

Tags: java, spring

I am using the spring expression language to parse some expressions. I run into a scenario that the context to run the expression against is a map or a dynamic bean created by BeanUtils

```
Map<String, Object> props= new HashMap<>();
props.put("name", "john");
ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
EvaluationContext context = new StandardEvaluationContext();
Expression exp = parser.parseExpression("name==john");
boolean s  = exp.getValue(context, Boolean.class);
```

This blows up as the name is not a public property defined in the context.Any idea of how the spring expression language can be used to achieve such functionality

Answer (score 10):

There are two errors in your code. First, you need to use single quotes around the literal string `'john'` in the expression. Second, you need to pass the variable `props` as the root object of the context. After fixing these, you need to use `MapAcessor` as the property accessor to access map properties directly:

```
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put("name", "john");
    ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
    StandardEvaluationContext context = new StandardEvaluationContext(props);
    context.addPropertyAccessor(new MapAccessor());
    Expression exp = parser.parseExpression("name=='john'");
    boolean s  = exp.getValue(context, Boolean.class);
```

Answer (score 2):

As @Marco said there are a few modifications that needs to be done.

1. Use single quotes around the literal string `'john'` in the expression.
2. You need to pass the variable props as the root object of the context.
3. But we can directly access the Map using [SpEL](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions) as Mentioned in the documentation

   ```
   // Officer's Dictionary

   Inventor pupin = parser.parseExpression("Officers['president']").getValue(
           societyContext, Inventor.class);
   ```
4. Use `#this['name']`.[Using #this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions-this-root)

> The variable #this is always defined and refers to the current
>   evaluation object (against which unqualified references are resolved).

After modification the code will look like this :

```
    Map<String, Object> props= new HashMap<>();
    props.put("name", "john");
    ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
    EvaluationContext context = new StandardEvaluationContext(props);
    Expression exp = parser.parseExpression("#this['name']=='john'");
    boolean s  = exp.getValue(props, Boolean.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

@John Kiragu you can achieve that by creating a custom property accessor that will work with a map.Then make use of the SimpleEvaluationContext. See example below:

```
  PropertyAccessor accessor = new MyCustomPropertyAccessor();
  SimpleEvaluationContext evaluationContext = new SimpleEvaluationContext.Builder(accessor).
                        withRootObject(contextObject).build();
enter code here
```

Your Custom properties accessor will then override the read method:

```
public class MyCustomPropertyAccessor implements PropertyAccessor {

    @Override
    public boolean canRead(EvaluationContext context, Object target, String name) throws AccessException {
      // your custom code

    }
    @Override
    public TypedValue read(EvaluationContext context, Object target, String name) throws AccessException {
    // your custom code

    }
}
```

Also if a map doesn't work for you, then give `DynaClass` a shot.